# I am trying to download the Yearly data from this website using python but i am not sure how to approach it?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-collection

I want to learn how to download the CSV files for the last ten years using python. I think this would be helpful.

https://www.usgovernmentspending.com/compare_state_debt

My attempts involve requests and pandas.

Comment: Welcome to `Stackoverflow`, please check [ask], also be informed that `StackOverflow` is not for assigning your `homework` or `work` tasks. please [edit] your question and show for us what you have tried with and what you failed with.

Comment: I am just trying to improve my skills

Answer (score 1):

This is a multipart problem and I'm going to outline the steps I think you should use.

- The first part is going to be simply downloading the webpage. What I would suggest is use something like [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) to get the webpage
- Once you have that you can use [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the webpage.
- I took a look at the website and it looks like there are a number of ways you could download the data. I think the best way to get the data is going to be to extract all the text from [this](https://www.usgovernmentspending.com/compare_state_debt#copypaste) particular part in the page.
- Once you do that you are probably going to need to clean up the data. I suggest using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for that.

People on here aren't going to solve the whole problem for you. That said, if you get stuck along the way and have a specific question, StackOverflow can probably help at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved I managed to solve it using selenium.

By doing the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver # allow launching browser
# Opening in incognito
driver_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#driver_option.add_argument(" — incognito")
chromedriver_path = '# Write your path here' # Change this to your own chromedriver path!

# Creating a webdriver.
def create_webdriver():
 return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=driver_option)

URL = ""

browser.get(url)
# Clicking the button.
elem1 = browser.find_element_by_link_text("download file")
# Clicking the button.
elem1.click()
```

I put the previous code in a loop for all the years until 2020 and I got all the files in CSV format